# Outlook 2007 paragraph width issue

Tags: html, email, outlook

Outlook 2007 doesn't seem to take the width setting on the `<P>` tag in my html email, my code looks like:

```
<p style="padding-left:8px;width:700px;font-family: Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:16px;">
```

Any way I can work around this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like what code?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `<div>` tag instead of a `<p>` tag as `<p>` tags are not ment to be more than showing where a paragraph begins and ends. Where as a `<div>` tag is a section of the document that can be set to be any width and height that you set.

---

Maybe try a `<table>` with one cell it has width and height tags built in so you don't need css. You can hide the border by setting border to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. True, it's better to use div tag, however, even with div, I still can't set width, cause Outlook 2007 doesn't seem to support width in styles.

Comment: odd. Sounds like its a problem with microsoft being old on the uptakes. It also might be for security so that all of css is disabled so that links are not hidden.

Comment: Maybe try a table with one cell it has width and height tags built in so you don't need css. You can hide the border by setting border to 0.

Comment: @CGeniusGo is right, tables are the safest option for email html

Comment: Right, that's the solution I went with. Thanks!